# Testing Components with a Parent Class (extends) using injector dependencies

Tags: angular, testing, mocking, components, extends

using: Angular 7.2 / Node 10

I have a base class which injects a whole bunch of services. Many components then Extend this base class, and thereby gets access to all those injected service and other ancillary helper functions. It works well for the App in question for this code stack I'm working on, but now I want to write tests, and it is not practical to refactor the Extended class into an injected 'service' as elsewhere suggested.

How best can I test a component with this structure?

BaseClass - has several dependency injected services and helper funcions.

Many Components extend this BaseClass, the component's constructor just calls super();

eg:

```
export class PageBase implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
 
  constructor(
    public _someService: SomeService = InjectorService.injector.get(SomeService)
    // etc
  ) {
  }

  // init function that's used on child pages - called from ngOnInit
  pageInit(): void { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    // other setup
  }

  variousCommonFunctions(): any {
    // etc etc etc
  }

}



export class SomeComponent extends PageBase {

  constructor() {
    super();

    // other setup
  }
   
  pageInit(): void {
    // some setup to pass to PageBase...
  }
}
```

Does anyone know how to handle this situation?

I'm not finding any satisfactory, working examples, which fit this use case.

Any ideas? thanks :)